too large dataframe python spider
I tried to load an excel file on Pandas and process it.
I use large excel files. For example I'm working on a file with 50 columns. I'd like to see it on spider but when I use Print functions, everytime a part of columns will be hidden with 3 points. See the attached picture.
I see someone suggest use Jupiter, is this the only solution?
I tried to use print, display and tabulate but nothing worked.
I expect someone to give me simple suggestion. I'm not a professional developer.
#EXAMPLE FOR QUESTION
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan21': [22, 20, 25, 30, 4, 8, 12, 10]})

    
df['Feb21'] = df.Jan21*3
df['Mar21'] = df.Jan21*0.2
df['Apr21'] = df.Jan21*1.23
df['Mag21'] = df.Jan21*2.5
df['Giu21'] = df.Jan21*3
df['Lug21'] = df.Jan21*4.2
df['Ago21'] = df.Jan21*0.25
df['Set21'] = df.Jan21*2.5
df['Ott21'] = df.Jan21*2.7
df['Nov21'] = df.Jan21*3
df['Dic21'] = df.Jan21*0.33
df['Jan22'] = df.Jan21*1.89
df['Feb22'] = df.Jan21*2.65

print ("Monthly sales")
print (df)

For example, if I process this simple code, in the end you will see that only few columns of dataframe will be visible. I tried Jupiter but it also had the same problem.

Why does this have the web-crawler tag

To see all columns, you can adjust the pandas display settings to avoid truncated output.
1. Option 1: Adjust pandas display options
You can change the display option for maximum columns.
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

print("Monthly sales")
print(df)

2. Option 2: Use to_string() for full dataframe display
You can use to_string() to show entire dataframe without truncated columns.
print("Monthly sales")
print(df.to_string())

I hope this will help you a little.

thank you Dear, let me try your solution. I see The first step work well but I need run the code on Jupiter to see more clearly the large dataframe. Jupiter allow to scroll the dataframe.
